# Sim Problem After installing custom rom

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean

I have qmobile Noir A600 It has same specifications Of canvas a116 As We do t have any cuatom rom So i installed ro.s of canvas But now sim is not detected every thing is working fine...Is there is any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is never a good idea to flash a ROM that is not for a specific device onto a device.  With that being said, there are multiple reasons (i.e. different memory locations for the SIM circuit, different microcontroller, etc) that could be causing your issue.  My advise is to reflash the stock ROM and see if that fixes your problem.  If so then PLEASE do not flash a ROM that is not for your device.  It is to the point now (say with the HTC One M7) that you won't receive signal if you flash a ROM of a different carrier even.